# set inline-block css with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

based on this example from @Bergi [jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/1321/](http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/1321/) 
the code below work fine:

```
#center{
display:inline-block;
}
```

but if I try this don't work in Chrome and Safari

```
$('#center').css('display','inline-block');
```

nor

```
document.getElementById('center').style.display='inline-block';
```

any solution? thanks.

EDIT ... 
ok now I understand why you say it work fine. I have tried it in Chrome (v30) and safari v5.1 And not work ... but yes it work In Explorer, Firefox, and Opera. So now the question is ... some solution for Chrome and Safari ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Oh, and regarding your fiddle: You're loading Mootools there; have you actually included the jQuery library?

Comment: @bergi. Thanks for asking but NOT. The element is found (I tested with other css properties and works) ... The fiddle example is not mine ... I had tried it with jquery

Comment: Then please show us what exactly you have done (create a demo that exhibits that behaviour), your code should be working.

Comment: @Bergi So.  Try to paste display:inline-block;  in  the css #center of this example http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/1320/ and you will see how the 3 divs become in one line.

Comment: As soon as I change the jQuery version to one that runs in my browser, it works flawlessly: http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/1321/

Comment: @Bergi I am used to `js`, but too lazy to learn `css`, so I prefer a js solution.

Comment: @Timo You have to learn css regardless when you want to do styling, no matter whether you set the styles from js or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#center').css('display', 'inline-block');` works if you're using jQuery. See: http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/1320/ . Change it to `block` and back.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#center').css('display','inline-block');
```

This works fine as previously stated by PHPglue, (when you actually set the fiddle to use jquery instead of Mootools) the issue with the right div not displaying inline is due to your use of both a float and the display-inline property, they're not really compatible with each other.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Pure JS` code to show the use of `block-inline`:

```js
    withElem = document.querySelector('#withSpace')
    withoutElem = document.querySelector('#withoutSpace')
    btn1 = document.createElement('button')
    btn1.textContent = 'element1'
    btn2 = document.createElement('button')
    btn2.textContent = 'element2'
    btn3 = document.createElement('button')
    btn3.textContent = 'element1'
    btn4 = document.createElement('button')
    btn4.textContent = 'element2'

    spn = document.createElement('span')
    spn.style.display = 'inline-block'
    // Get a spacer of 20px:
    spn.style.width = '20px'
    //Append it to another node
    withElem.append(btn1, spn, btn2)
    withoutElem.append(btn3, btn4)
```

```html
<div id=withSpace></div><br>
<div id=withoutSpace></div>
```

:
spn.style.width = '20px'
//Append it to another node
parentElem.appendChild(spn)